# Java Inheritance and Constructor Arguments

Tags: java, inheritance

I am amateur in Java please help me.

I have a class: **Account**

```
public class Account {
    protected String fullName;
    protected String accontNumber;
    protected String password;
    protected int balance;

    public Account(String name, String acc_num, String pass, int b){
        fullName = name;
        accontNumber = acc_num;
        password = pass;
        balance = b;
    }
}
```

and I going to create a new class **Account2** that inherit from **Account**

```
public class Account2 extends Account{
    public Account2(String l){
        String[] temp = l.split(",");
        super.fullName = temp[0];
        super.accontNumber = temp[1];
        super.password = temp[2];
        super.balance = Integer.parseInt(temp[3]);
    }

}
```

But I receive an error message that say:  ***Actual and formal argument list are differ in length***

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what was your's input value?

Comment: an string that contains super class's constructor's parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the base class has a non-default constructor (one or more parameter), the derived class must call the base class constructor in its constructor with `super(paramters)`. And also notice for constructor, you must have the first line with the super statement, so you must declare a construct with the same parameter, or correctly pass in the parameter within one line, though this is not recommended:

```
public Account2(String l) {
    super(l.split(",")[0],l.split(",")[1],l.split(",")[2],Integer.parseInt(l.split(",")[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

do like this

```
public class Account2 extends Account{
    public Account2(String l){            
        super(l.split(",")[0],l.split(",")[1],l.split(",")[2],Integer.parseInt(l.split(",")[3]))      
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Invocation of a superclass constructor be the first line in the subclass constructor?

Comment: Shouldn't Invocation of a superclass constructor be the first line in the subclass constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't placed the `super` constructor call. So by default it will try to pick `super()` i.e. no-argument constructor which is not present in `Account` class

Answer (score 1):

Your current subclass constructor sets the values of the superclass parameters after superclass construction. If you would like to keep that approach, add a no-arg constructor to the superclass that sets default values.

It would be better to use setters rather than accessing the fields directly.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO in this case you sholudn't use a constructor. Create a static method that takes your `String` input, validates it, splits it into some logical parts and then uses *"normal"* constructor to create an object:

```
class Account2 extends Account {
    Account2(String name, String acc_num, String pass, int b) {
        super(name, acc_num, pass, b);
    }

    public static Account2 createFromString(String input) {
        String[] temp = l.split(",");

        if (temp.length != 4) {
            throw new RuntimeException("...");
        }

        return new Account2(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], Integer.parseInt(temp[3]));
    }
}
```

Your code will be a lot cleaner in my personal opinion:

```
Account2 acc1 = new Account2("abc", "def", "ghi", 2);
Account2 acc2 = Account2.createFromString("abc,def,ghi,2");
```

Answer (score 1):

The probelm:

**Actual and formal argument list are differ in length**

To understand this, a basic understanding of constructors and their behavior under inheritance will help you.

1. When we define a class without constructors, the compiler inserts a zero argument constructor by itself.
2. If we write our own constructor with some argument then this default constructor is not inserted by compiler and if required, it has to be added explicitly.
3. When an instance of a subclass is created , there is an implicit call (very first thing to get executed during constructor invocation) to the superclass constructor by default.
4. So, if there is **no default constructor** in superclass (which will be the case when we define our own custom constructor with argument), the compiler will complain.
5. To get around this, you need to call the constructor with argument as very first line in the subclass constructor or define a default constructor explicitly.